# what are effects of factory reset while in rooted condition of mobile

Tags: rooting, factory-reset, unrooting, supersu

Question : what are effects of factory reset while in rooted condition of mobile

In my lyf water 7 mobile device having 16gb internal memory and 2 gb ram and 64gb external sd card

I had first factory rest my mobile with and formatted my external sd card with no user apps or data installed then I decided to root it and before that want to take a backup

I had loaded twrp recovery (fastboot boot twrprecovery.img) in bootloader mode and took NANDROID backup of system boot cache userdata through twrp backup menu and through adb pull tool all partitions backup of mmcblk0 and system boot recovery userdata and all in other partitions in devices.

Then In twrp menu install menu I installed superuser .apk after installing succesfully  I rebooted to android 5.1.1 rooted version

Through root checker i checked the rooting status ita good

Then I download link2sd plus modified  parched .apk file which installed successfully and to open it asked to grant root permission for 15 minutes and disappeared and I tried  to locate its icon in main menu or front wall but no success. I thought to uninstall but there is no mark in any settings>apps installed or running list

I tried to find in root folders but it's hidden or disappears name there to

I m wooried it's not any virus malware or spyware  apk file which asked executed or hidden .. I thought to factory reset to erase that hidden  apk file of link2sd

My queries:-

1. How to find and erase that hidden apk file aftermarks or settings
2. Should I format or factory reset the mobile as su was installed or I should first unroot or clear su before factory reset will it erase that malware hidden  aftermarks
3. If I don't not remove or unroot SU  and factory reset the mobile then will after factory reset I have to re root or install SU again or it will be rooted or unrooted automatically after factory reset format withing rooting

Comment: you can find and uninstall hidden apps from official Link2SD app

Comment: @alecx Installing Chainfire's SuperSU with TWRP.  http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu

Comment: How I rooted installed superuser through recovery https://www.howtogeek.com/115297/how-to-root-your-android-why-you-might-want-to/

Comment: Chainfire's SuperSU.zip resides in boot and userdata, re-rooting is required after userdata was formatted (aka factory reset) although device becomes not fully unrooted because modifications in boot survives

Comment: to remove any malware just restore (full) TWRP backup from menu

Comment: @alecxs bro thanks for commenting kindly copy ur coment to an answer so that I can accept the answer for question please

Answer (score 0):

1. you can find and uninstall hidden apps from official Link2SD app
2. to remove any malware just restore (full) TWRP backup from menu
3. Chainfire's SuperSU.zip resides in boot and userdata, re-rooting is required after userdata was formatted (aka factory reset) although device becomes not fully unrooted because modifications in boot survive